# Photoshop animation: Contour lines from one frame kept in the second frame of animation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I'm creating a gif animation of a castle where the first frame is the castle constructed and the second frame is the castle destroyed. I have to place the image on a website.

The issue I'm facing is that in the second frame, the contour of the constructed castle appears along with the other image.

I tried to copy and paste the castle into another layer but it didn't work out.
I also tried to contract the selection so it would take the border away.

It worked in some way, but when I placed it on the website, it shows the contour just like before.

See my screenshots below:

[image: Frame 1]

[image: No countour]

[image: Frame 2]

[image: Frame 2 - no contour]

[image: Site - with contour]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your screenshots it's clear that the "ghost" stroke is present somewhere inside the "components" group in some of the layers. I suggest you add a white background layer to your PSD so you can see the shapes clearly while you edit the animation.

Comment: Thanks Luciano. Indeed, there was in one of the components.